# What does Page: matches regex ".*" mean?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I imported a list of Google Remarketing Lists, and I had created an "All Users" list which contains 50k users and when I imported this new list with that regex expression and a description that also says All Users, the list shows up as 25k.

So what exactly does matches regex ".*" mean or how is it different from just Page contains "/".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In regular expression syntax the period `.` mean "match any character" and the asterisk `*` means "any number of times".

So it basically means match anything (even an empty string). It shouldn't filter out anything.

Comment: I believe that "." means a single character except for a new line or line terminator.